# How to change default binding of ENTER for Sign In submit in Bootstrap template?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use template: `http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html`. I have in `nav-bar` additional input which is used for quick search. It should be triggered by keyup ENTER. Tried to bind ENTER key using jQuery:

```
$('#search-input').keyup(function(event){

        if (event.keyCode == 13 ) {

            getSearchStr();

        }
```

Didn't worked. Seems like it already defined for `Sign In` button. How to redefine it?

---

UPADTE:

```
$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {

    alert("Working....");

});
```

AND

```
<form name="search-form" id="search-form" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return getSearchStr()">
    <input class="navbar-search" id="search-input" type="text" name="search-txt" placeholder="Search keywords...">
</form>
```

---

UPDATE2:

As long as input#search-input wrapped in form#search-form, I guess form data will be posted  if enter key is pressed. If form has "onsubmit" then appropriate JS func is being called. If the func returns true the form gets submitted, if false then not. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind to key or click events if you really want to be listening for when a form is submitted. If you want to listen for when a form is submitted, do just that:

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

<sup>(assuming the form has an `id` of `login_form`)</sup>

Comment: Can I leave just one <input> for search purpose, without wrapping it with <form> and allow JS to take proper actions? How? I have <input  id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">

Comment: @RCola: You *can*, but I'd very much recommend against it. Wrap it in a form; it's not that hard and it'll make it easier for your website to degrade gracefully in the face of JavaScript being disabled.

Comment: Wrapped in form but anyways the function is not invoked. Why?

Comment: I guess the problem was - i put this func inside * $(document).ready*.  Am I right?

Comment: @RCola: Yes. JSFiddle did that for me, but I could [just as easily do it explicitly](http://jsfiddle.net/7eyZv/embedded/result,html,js/).